# CSS effects for elements in the menu list of the course inside LMS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Learning Management System OLAT allows creating styles/design with CSS when creating your online course.
some sections of a course's site with the appropriate ID or class selectors are displayed on the screenshot.

How can i reach each of the elements in the left menu (number 3) to apply hover effects for them, if i know that their CSS ID-Selector: „#o_main_left_content?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
Using tree class because it represents lists of that type!



/* tree on top */
.o_tree ul li .active_parent.o_tree_link a:hover, .o_tree ul li,  .active_parent.o_tree_link a,
.o_tree ul li .active_parent.o_tree_link a:hover, .o_tree ul li,     .active_parent.o_tree_link a:focus
{
color: #84A311;
}
```